# Symfony2 custom (HTML5) date field creation

Tags: symfony, custom-controls

My target is to create a custom Date field (which should work with Doctrine). The main difference with the basic Symfony's one is that it shouldn't be 3 dropdowns, but one `<input type="date">`.

I've tried several tutorials like [Symfony's book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) and some helpful answers here.

However the more solutions I try to embed, the more problems I see.

Could anybody write or advise the tutorial for this task?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [date field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html) supports [that](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#widget) already. Just set the `widget` option to `single_text` and voila — you'll have what you want. No need to create a special type for that. :)

Comment: Thanks for an answer! However it renders '<input type="text">' while i still want it to be 'type="date"'

Comment: Figured it out wit the help of http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#cookbook-form-theming-methods

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony >= 2.6 they introduced a `html5` option which will generate a HTML5 input element.

You can see the documentation here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#html5